# Windows 10 IOT with RFM12B Module

Tags: spi, windows-iot

Is there a way to get the a RFM12B radio module work with a Raspberry 2 (Windows 10 IOT) over SPI? Can I connect the RFM12B directly to the Raspberry?
Are there any code examples in C#?

Comment: I don't think you will find a ready made solution for this one, as win 10 is relatively new, but i am sure if you know how to use SPI in win10, it should not be a problem.

Comment: Can you recommend a tutorial for SPI on Win 10 IOT?

Comment: I would stick to official guide. This link seems to be a good starting point. https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/StartCoding.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code how to initialise SPI in WinIoT. You first need to enable GPIO, then the SPI.

```
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Spi;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using DisplayFont;

/* Initialize GPIO, SPI, and the display */
private async void InitAll()
{
    try
    {
        InitGpio();             /* Initialize the GPIO controller and GPIO pins */
        await InitSpi();        /* Initialize the SPI controller                */
    }
    /* If initialization fails, display the exception and stop running */
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Text_Status.Text = "Exception: " + ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Text_Status.Text += "\nInner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        return;
    }

    Text_Status.Text = "Initialized";
}

/* Initialize the GPIO */
private void InitGpio()
{
    try
    {
        IoController = GpioController.GetDefault(); /* Get the default GPIO controller on the system */

        /* Initialize a pin as output for the Data/Command line on the display  */
        DataCommandPin = IoController.OpenPin(DATA_COMMAND_PIN);
        DataCommandPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        DataCommandPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

        /* Initialize a pin as output for the hardware Reset line on the display */
        ResetPin = IoController.OpenPin(RESET_PIN);
        ResetPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        ResetPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
    }
    /* If initialization fails, throw an exception */
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("GPIO initialization failed", ex);
    }
}
/* Initialize the SPI bus */
private async Task InitSpi()
{
    try
    {
        var settings = new SpiConnectionSettings(SPI_CHIP_SELECT_LINE); /* Create SPI initialization settings                               */
        settings.ClockFrequency = 10000000;                             /* Datasheet specifies maximum SPI clock frequency of 10MHz         */
        settings.Mode = SpiMode.Mode3;                                  /* The display expects an idle-high clock polarity, we use Mode3
                                                                         * to set the clock polarity and phase to: CPOL = 1, CPHA = 1
                                                                         */

        string spiAqs = SpiDevice.GetDeviceSelector(SPI_CONTROLLER_NAME);       /* Find the selector string for the SPI bus controller          */
        var devicesInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(spiAqs);         /* Find the SPI bus controller device with our selector string  */
        SpiDisplay = await SpiDevice.FromIdAsync(devicesInfo[0].Id, settings);  /* Create an SpiDevice with our bus controller and SPI settings */

    }
    /* If initialization fails, display the exception and stop running */
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("SPI Initialization Failed", ex);
    }
}
```

And in your main code, you will define the PINs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    /* Important! Uncomment the code below corresponding to your target device */

    /* Uncomment for MinnowBoard Max */
    //private const string SPI_CONTROLLER_NAME = "SPI0";  /* For MinnowBoard Max, use SPI0                            */
    //private const Int32 SPI_CHIP_SELECT_LINE = 0;       /* Line 0 maps to physical pin number 5 on the MBM          */
    //private const Int32 DATA_COMMAND_PIN = 3;           /* We use GPIO 3 since it's conveniently near the SPI pins  */
    //private const Int32 RESET_PIN = 4;                  /* We use GPIO 4 since it's conveniently near the SPI pins  */

    /* Uncomment for Raspberry Pi 2 */
    private const string SPI_CONTROLLER_NAME = "SPI0";  /* For Raspberry Pi 2, use SPI0                             */
    private const Int32 SPI_CHIP_SELECT_LINE = 0;       /* Line 0 maps to physical pin number 24 on the Rpi2        */
    private const Int32 DATA_COMMAND_PIN = 22;          /* We use GPIO 22 since it's conveniently near the SPI pins */
    private const Int32 RESET_PIN = 23;                 /* We use GPIO 23 since it's conveniently near the SPI pins */

    // ... the rest of your code
}
```